# Parameterless action responding to request with parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the usual simple `Index` ActionResult without any parameters at it's signature inside `Home` controller in my app.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
    return View();
}
```

When I type .../Home/Index/example as an url this controller answers the request.

I'm guessing this has something to do with my route config.

This is my route-config

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }).RouteHandler = new DashRouteHandler();

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Exception",
            routeTemplate: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ErrorHandling", action = "Exception" }
        );
    }
}
```

I don't know how to prevent it. Simply, I don't want such calls to be answered, instead I want them to be directed to 404 page.

Comment: `public ActionResult Index(string id = null){ if(id != null) [redirectTo404]; [do whatever you want index to do] }`

Comment: Also maybe there's a way to create a custom `Attribute` that will handle unparameterized actions you want to act this way, so then you could just add `[CustomUnparameterized]` before your action

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain why you want the application to react in this way? Maybe someone has a better approach of tackling the issue.

Comment: Well, because such behaviour got reported in our Qualys report and we need to solve it.

Comment: What do you think `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` means?

Comment: I know what it means but what's its relevance with my problem?

Comment: That route means `if I see a url with three parts, go to the controller and action specified`. It literally did exactly what you told it to do. If you don't want it to work like that, make a route like `"Home/Index/{id}"` and route it to your 404 page or wherever you want it to do. Be sure to specify that route **before** `Default`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a parameter `string id` and change your Index Method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    if(id != null)
    {
        return StatusCode(404);
    }
    ...
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I would've used `string` instead of `int?` what do you expect to happen if you call `.../Home/Index/example`?

Comment: The 1st option will not work, because it will not match, but it will match the `Default` route

Comment: thanks for the comments, I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I thought about this but this solution targets only a single action in a probably wider problem, I feel like I need something more general